# How do you say ‘outré’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

It’s not in Wells, Benson, Vikivortaro, nor Reta Vortaro.

Here's the link to the Merriam-Webster entry on it:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outre

Comment: Care to define what *you* mean by that and add some context, maybe an example sentence? An English equivalent might be helpful too.

Comment: A sentence is good because usually we translate ideas, meanings. The translation might even depend on usage (happy: gaja, feliĉa, senzorga,...). It's hard, or near impossible to translate `outre` without context, given your definition: "bizarre, bizarro, cranky, crazy, curious, eccentric, erratic, far-out, funky, funny, kinky, kooky (also kookie), odd, off-kilter, off-the-wall, offbeat, out-of-the-way, outlandish, peculiar, quaint, queer, queerish, quirky, remarkable, rum [chiefly British], screwy, spaced-out, strange, wacky (also whacky), way-out, weird, weirdo, wild"

Comment: All of the above. What I'm wanting is the 'missing entry' in Benson.

Comment: I'm not an English native speaker but I think that "aŭdaca" may be a suitable single word translation for "violating convention or propriety". As always, by the way, it depends on the context.

Comment: You want "all of the above" translations? Search them words in a dictionary. Otherwise provide context.

Answer (score 2):

To me, "outré " means "outlandish", which I translate as "bizara".

In this article in The Economist - https://tinyurl.com/yhu658mm - , "outré " appears in the same context as "wacky" (arlekeneca, literally: "clownish") and "daft" (ridinda).

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus «fia» sed ankaŭ uzus «fi-» por aliigi la signifon de la vorto laŭ via bezono. Ekzemple: His outré outburst was embarrassing to his wife. -> Lia fiekkrio estis embarasa por sia edzino. AŬ Lia fia ekkrio estis embarasa por sia edzino.

Angle:

I would say «fia» but also would use «fi-» to modify the meaning of the word to your need. For example: His outré outburst was embarrassing to his wife. -> Lia fiekkrio estis embarasa por sia edzino. OR Lia fia ekkrio estis embarasa por sia edzino.

Answer (score 0):

Mi foje aŭdis "skurila/e"

Comment: Bonvenon ĉe [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! Can you give more details where or from whom you've heard "skurila" / "skurile"? Might it be a term used only by an individual or a small group, or have you observed more widespread usage? Does it occur in any dictionaries? (I've found it in [neither PIV](https://vortaro.net/#skurile_kd) [nor ReVo](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-1e.html?q=skurila) yet.)

Comment: Eble estas germanismo. Verdire, mi neniam aúdis la vorton "outré" en la angla, kaj ne certas pri ties signifo

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus : oza, ozita, ozeca.  -ozo estas neoficiala sed neforigebla sufikso kiu signifas "malagrable, provokante aŭ simple supermezure rimarkinda pro sia konsisteco, aŭ enhavo en tio".  Oficiale la sufikso signas suferon aŭ malbonestadon pro malsana aŭ malfunkcia korpoparto, sed facile povas tia senco estiĝi figura.  Tro rimarkinda hepato, videble blovita do ne tre sana hepato, rezultas en hepatozon.

Outré, kune kun osé, tradukas tiun realecon en la francan. Romanoza rakonto estas rakonto decide tro romaneska por la temo.